# How to create a Xamarin foreground service

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Trying to create my first Xamarin foreground service but can't find a suitable example. The examples in Microsoft documentation seem to be either incomplete or use depreciated Notification.Builder:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/applicationfundamentals-servicesamples-foregroundservicedemo/

I've found ONE code example that seems to be up to date, but I'm struggling to decipher how it works by looking at the code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android-o-androidplaylocation-locupdfgservice/

Can anyone give me an example of how to create basic foreground service?

Comment: rather thank ask us to provide yet another tutorial, why don't you ask a question about the specific thing(s) that you do not understand in the sample that you've found?

Comment: Jason The sample is convoluted, is hard to know the right questions to ask, this is why I've asked for a basic example which I've not been able to find.

Comment: Read the Android foreground services docs. There are not _that_ many moving parts. The sample is in its purest form it can be in.

Comment: @Cheesebaron The example uses Notification.Builder which is obsolete so the example doesn't work.

Comment: It uses NotificationCompat. Just replace with Notification.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification @DavidAndrewThorpe

Comment: That location update foreground service has bugs. But first you should refactor out nonsense like using class names as variable names, etc. Once you have done that the code will make more sense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have finally stitched together an answer. Here is an example for anyone who find themselves here:

Create a Dependency Service so you can call your Start/Stop service methods from your shared code.

Make Interface:

```
public interface IAndroidService
    {
        void StartService();

        void StopService();
    }
```

Implement a class within your android project which uses the interface. Remember to add assembly reference.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidServiceHelper))]

namespace YourNameSpace.Droid
{
    internal class AndroidServiceHelper : IAndroidService
    {
        private static Context context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;

        public void StartService()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(DataSource));

            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                context.StartForegroundService(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                context.StartService(intent);
            }
        }

        public void StopService()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(DataSource));
            context.StopService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we do pretty much the same (create interface and implement in class within android project) for creating the notification needed for a Foreground Service:

The interface for creating notifications

```
public interface INotification
    {
        Notification ReturnNotif();
    }
```

Create a class inside of the android project that implements INotification so we can create and return a notification object which we need to start a Foreground Service. Remember to add the assembly reference:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NotificationHelper))]

namespace MetroAlarmHandlerMobile.Droid
{
    internal class NotificationHelper : INotification
    {
        private static string foregroundChannelId = "9001";
        private static Context context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;


        public Notification ReturnNotif()
        {
            // Building intent
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            intent.PutExtra("Title", "Message");

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, foregroundChannelId)
                .SetContentTitle("Your Title")
                .SetContentText("Main Text Body")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.MetroIcon)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            // Building channel if API verion is 26 or above
            if (global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(foregroundChannelId, "Title", NotificationImportance.High);
                notificationChannel.Importance = NotificationImportance.High;
                notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.EnableVibration(true);
                notificationChannel.SetShowBadge(true);
                notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });

                var notifManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                if (notifManager != null)
                {
                    notifBuilder.SetChannelId(foregroundChannelId);
                    notifManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                }
            }

            return notifBuilder.Build();
        }
}
```

Create a class that inherits and overrides from Service. This is a class created in your shared code and is where we will call the methods that we want to run on the Foreground Service.

```
public class DataSource : Service
    {

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public const int ServiceRunningNotifID = 9000;

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Notification notif = DependencyService.Get<INotification>().ReturnNotif();
            StartForeground(ServiceRunningNotifID, notif);

            _ = DoLongRunningOperationThings();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        public override bool StopService(Intent name)
        {
            return base.StopService(name);
        }


}
```

You can now start and stop your Foreground Service using Dependency Service anywhere in your shared code using the following code:

Start

```
DependencyService.Get<IAndroidService>().StartService();
```

Stop

```
DependencyService.Get<IAndroidService>().StopService();
```

Comment: Inheriting from Service must be done in the Android project, not in cross-platform shared code.

Comment: @MondQ DataSource is the name of the static class I've created which inherits from Service and implements methods such as OnStartCommand, StopService, OnDestroy etc... So where it says typeof(DataSource) you need to replace 'DataSource' with the class that you are using to inherit from Service.'

Comment: If OnStartCommand is not fired try adding [Service] above the DataSource  class

Comment: Is there a way to know if the service is already started?

Comment: A simple way is to create a bool like IsServiceStarted and set that to true/false when you start/stop it. You can just check that bool to know if it's been started or not

Comment: You should write an article with this! :) Or if you don't want to, I can write and publish one for the community. You can see my others here https://prototypemakers.medium.com

Comment: You are more than welcome to write an article using this example, just reference me somewhere so I can show to other people and act cool hahahaha

Comment: Thanks for this example! I just have a small question about the DoLongRunningOperationThings() method. I have a connection to server which I have to maintain in this method as long the app is in the background. Is this method called every x time? Or do I need to create my own looping in this method? Thank you!

Comment: Okay so I understand you'll have your network code called from the service so it should keep running. Any code used to maintain this connection should be called within the methods that were called from the service. To clarify, you don't need to keep starting the foreground service in a loop to maintain the connection.

Comment: Thank you for example, but I do not see any notification + I can't handle `DataSource` behaviour. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There are 2 missing things in the answer : (1) Add [Service] above DataSource Class (2) DataSource class will not be created inside shared-code, instead it will be created under Android Project.

Comment: Also @DavidAndrewThorpe, how I can get already running foreground service?

Comment: `foregroundChannelId = "9001"` and `ServiceRunningNotifID = 9000` what those values do and why they are 9001 and 9000?

Comment: Does anyone know how to resolve the dependency in the service in MAUI? `DependencyService` was replaced with `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`, but I don't know how to get the `ServiceProvider` in platform specific code.

Answer (score 3):

The question should probably be, "How should I find examples for uncommon Xamarin Native functionality?"

If you are looking for examples for uncommon functionality, your best friend is GitHub:

- Just login to GitHub and in the search bar look for the name of the function on all of GitHub, `StartForegroundServiceCompat` in our case.
- And voilà, you can now [see all the public repos](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=StartForegroundServiceCompat&type=Code) that use that functionality!

Don't forget to write an article and provide an example thats up to date, explaining how it works!

Comment: Thank you for the idea buddy, I've not been using github but in light of what you've said, I probably should!

Comment: No problem! Yeah, it's actually a great resource after StackOverflow & the MS Xamarin Docs!

Comment: @DavidAndrewThorpe let me know if you were able to find anything useful, and resolve this question if its done.