# How to register an app as a service on Android, C#

Tags: c#, foreground-service

I'm trying to develop an app mobile indicator for battery level, which advise at certain levels through an alarm (.wav file). All that is for Android and written in C# (Xamarin Visual Studio).

I took part of the code from here:
[How to create a Xamarin foreground service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079610/how-to-create-a-xamarin-foreground-service)

and put my code on github, here:
https://github.com/Python-program-maker/battery_level.git

What i don't understand is why my app don't be registered as a service on the mobile. I want the app go in background, so I used the Foreground service (because of Android >8.0). But it is just like this code is ignorated from the emulator (and the mobile too), so it works as a normal app, non registered a s a service. Can you help me to find the error?

Thanks.

UPDATING

I share the code of MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using Xamarin.Essentials;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BAT_SRV
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private double batt_lev;
        List<double> valoreControllo = new List<double>();
        

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Funzione_prova();
            DependencyService.Get<IAndroidService>().StartService();
            Battery.BatteryInfoChanged += Battery_BatteryInfoChanged;
            
        }

        void Battery_BatteryInfoChanged (Object sender, BatteryInfoChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            batt_lev = (double)e.ChargeLevel;
            batt_lev = Math.Round(batt_lev, 2);

            if (valoreControllo.Contains(batt_lev))
            {
                
                CounterLabel.Text = batt_lev.ToString("N2");
                DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("suono_123.wav");
                
            }

        }

        void Funzione_prova ()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    double f = Convert.ToDouble(i);
                    valoreControllo.Add(f/100);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question and share some code, but maybe this will help. An app that contains a `Service` still has to have an `Activity`. You can launch your service in the background by receiving an event like `BOOT_COMPLETED`. (If I remember the name correctly.) Note when you first install an app, and after force closing it, it's in a "stopped" state until the user opens an activity. An app in this state will never receive events like `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question sharing some code here, even if it is uploaded in github in the full version. What I need is to have at least at the very beginning installing an app, a notification on the phone, so I can know it is installed as a service.

Comment: "even if it is uploaded in github in the full version"...whether it's on GitHub is irrelevant to your question here. Read item number 1 at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to understand why :-)

Comment: I understand now, I hope my last change could help you to give me some direction in this problem, I'm quite new to C# and really I dont' know how to move in this issue.