# How do I run this method in timer even after the app is closed in Xamarin form?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a method on the sample content page (sample.XAML.cs) and I want to set this method in a timer and run every 10 seconds even after the app is killed or closed.

```cs
public async void AlarmStart()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("JsonFile").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OnlineValueClass>>(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using foreground service - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079610/how-to-create-a-xamarin-foreground-service

Comment: Foreground service is killed if the app is closed. Try to learn the limitations of the platform first. The platforms are not made for developers to do whatever they want, but to create a good experience for users. Allowing things like this could make phone useless after installing of an app that misuses this and users don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), an Android application no longer have the ability to run freely in the background. For more details about this, you can refer to [Background Execution Limits in Android 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80):

But you can try to restarted the service once it been finished by a `BroadcastReceive`r . The function of BroadcastReceiver is to receive a signal when someone or something kills the service; its role is to restart the service.

For more details, you can check an relative article by entering key words
`Creating a never ending background service in Android`. Though it's Java code, it's easy to understand and convert